# is there any way to move files at once different locatios in powershell

Tags: powershell

tried this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\testingPS -Recurse |? {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))} | move-item -destination "P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\testing" ,"P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\C"
```

Getting below error

```
Move-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Destination'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:140
+ ... destination "P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\testing" ,"P:\Users\SMarri\Deskt ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chain multiple `Move-Item`/`Copy-Item` commands by using the `-PassThru` parameter switch:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\testingPS -Recurse |Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
} |Move-item -Destination "P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\testing" -PassThru |Copy-Item -Destination "P:\Users\SMarri\Desktop\C"
```

`-PassThru` causes `Move-Item` to output the file after the move operation, making it available for `Copy-Item` to copy.

Comment: That's a clever way to avoid `ForEach-Object`!